# Efficient way of displaying lots of data with headers?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

So I have about 50 individual pieces of data that I have to display all at once. There are about 4-5 different sections where I separate the type of data.

For example, one section would look like this:

```
Header
    Field A: Value      Field D: Value
    Field B: Value      Field E: Value
    Field C: Value      Field F: Value
```

The XAML for this layout is similar to this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label 
        Content="Company" 
        Foreground="#666" 
        FontFamily="Helvetica, Arial" 
        FontSize="13" />
    <TextBlock 
        Text="VALUE" 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Padding="6"
        Foreground="#333" 
        FontSize="13" 
        FontFamily="Helvetica, Arial" />
</Grid>
```

What I'm looking for is a nice and clean way to separate different sections so it's less of a chore to find what I'm looking for (in terms of the XAML and not the UI) and easier to make changes. I'm finding that the more data I add the harder it is to make smaller changes.

I've looked into the `HeaderedContentControl` however that appears to be a strict one header value and one content value control. All sections share styles.

Comment: Have you tried using a DataGrid?

Comment: @Damokles: I hadn't thought of that. Let me try it out.

Comment: Have you tried a ListView/GridView with grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need something like this:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/GroupByFormattedValue (its silverlight version) but wpf look same. Telerik is paid controls, but with little effort you can develop own datagrid working same way.